# File rename fails with access denied (sharing violation)

Tags: windows, multithreading, filesystems

My program creates a file, writes to it, closes it, renames it to something else. For one customer, the rename often fails with a sharing violation and I have been unable to recreate this issue.

The program is asynchronous and multithreaded, where the create and write are guaranteed to have been completed at the time of close and rename, but the close and rename may happen in any order due to being in different threads.

The customer ensures me that there are no av or backup programs installed and we have tried with Windows Search disabled.

When the close happens before or after the rename everything works (the file is opened with shared read+write+delete flags). However, when they are happening very close in time it sometimes fails. When running with ProcessMonitor, the error does not occur.

I know that the rename is made up out of several file operations (open, set information, close at least), so I assume that it is possible for the file close to be interleaved with the file rename, which seems be at the heart of the problem.

I am going to be able to work around the issue by ensuring that the file is closed after the rename. But I don't understand exactly what causes the sharing violation and I would like to know more why this is an issue. **Can anyone give me more information on what happens?**

Comment: Well from your description it seems that the close/rename operations can happen in a sequence but not at the same time (or close). Why don't you just have a lock that ensures exclusive access to close or rename the file such that the two threads cannot do it at the same time?

Comment: @Tudor: Yes, I am able to ensure that I can avoid the issue by making sure that they do not happen at the same time. This is not what I am asking for though, I would like to get a better understanding of what happens, so that I can avoid similar issues in the future.

Comment: This is a common problem on Windows because of the nature and implication of how handles to file objects work. If you care to understand that better look at the difference between IRP_MJ_CLOSE and IRP_MJ_CLEANUP. Keep in mind that even without AV you have other processes like the indexer that could attempt to gain access to the file too. I recommend you be prepared to retry the operation for a short while (1 sec?).